# What determines domain value?

Tags: domains, domain-registration, cost, value

I want to buy a domain but everywhere I go they tell me that domain costs `$ 4000` who or what determines the value of this domain and why is it so high?

Comment: that is not true for new domains, I think your are trying to buy an old domain, instead buy a new domain you can get at very cheap rate everywhere try  godaddy.com, one.com. ....

Comment: @Bala it says that domain was created 2003 and is owned by buydomains.com, so that means they purchased it and now are selling for that price?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is a **premium domain**, then yes, it will be worth $4000. An example of that is `exda.com`, which I wanted to buy. I on the `.org` version for $10 a year. As for a description, from Google, they say:

> A Premium Domain is a domain name that is already registered and owned by someone, but made available for sale. Prices for Premium Domains range from a few hundred to a few thousand dollars depending on the specific domain and current market influences.

A few other requirements that make a domain premium is:

- Short names and acronyms
- Ussually `.com` or a domain like `date.me`
- One-word or *brandable* names
- Domains with high traffic and search volume

You could try the `.net`, or `.org` version of the domain which you want, than maybe you can get that instead of the actual one you are looking for. The reason why I am saying this is because, by the question, you do not have the $4000 to pay for the one you really want.

Comment: You are correct I do not have that amount of money at this time, and I just wanted to make sure that it is not a scam.